# How do I use my Application Resources from another window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my `App.xaml` file I have:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <LocalViewModels:SharedSettingsViewModel x:Key="SharedSettingsViewModel"/>
    <LocalViewModels:ApplicationSpecificSettingsViewModel x:Key="ApplicationSpecificSettingsViewModel" />
</Application.Resources>
```

How can I use those resources in another window?

For example, if I had those resources in the same window I would do:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationSpecificSettingsViewModel}}"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationSpecificSettingsViewModel}}"
```

Comment: IMO, ViewModels don't belong in resources, and they don't belong in XAML.

Comment: because they're not a purely UI-specific concept. And I like the VM-First approach, rather than the View-First approach.

Comment: @HighCore so in the case its the same as 2 static variables in my App.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with HighCore if you want to do it this is what you need to do. The following is a complete example.

Step one - create the viewmodel (which you have already done it seems)

```
namespace resourcesTest
{
    public class SharedViewModel
    {
        public string TestMessage
        {
            get { return "This is a test"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Step two - Add it to the app.xaml as a resource

```
<Application x:Class="resourcesTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:resourcesTest"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <local:SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModel"></local:SharedViewModel>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Step three - set the datacontext in your window - whichever one it may be and then you can make use of the data.

```
<Window x:Class="resourcesTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SharedViewModel}}">
        <Label Content="{Binding TestMessage}"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

unless I am missing something that is what you are trying to do. Again, I wouldn't do it this way - I would use the application resources for styles and UI specific things only. Hopefully that helps.